# Dividing rows when iterating in pandas using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a flask app where I am getting back data and transformed into pandas Dataframe.

```
if request.method == 'PUT':
   content = request.get_json(silent=True)
   df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(content)

   for index, row in df.iterrows():

       if row["label"] == True:
          row['A'] = row['B'] / row['C']
       elif row["label"] == False:
          row['A'] = row["B"]
          if row['D'] == 0:
             row['C'] = 0
          else:
             ...
```

What i am trying to do here is simple arithmetic like addition, subtraction & division.

I have used iterrows() mainly because i needed multiple values to iterate and perform calculations on specific row values. `df['..'].item()` didn't work in my use case.

Addition and subtraction work fine but division seems to slip out somehow and always returns values like `0`, `-1`, `1`

Example calculation

`row['A'] = row['B'] / row['C']`

Most of the time the values of `row['B']` is lesser than `row['C']`. Example values

`row['A'] = 1232455 / 26719856`

The only calculation involved in the app are addition, subtraction & division.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this (Here is an example):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'label': [True, False, True, True, False], 
    'A': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
    'B': [4, 24, 31, 21, 3],
    'C': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70],
    'D': [3645, 0, 27, 24, 96]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You can apply your changes directly on your main Dataframe without being required to iterate over each row each time like this :

```
# select only rows with label == True and apply the division function

df.loc[df.label == True, 'A'] = df['B']/df['C']

df.loc[df.label == False, 'A'] = df['B']

df.loc[np.logical_and(df.label == False, df.D == 0), 'C'] = 0 
.
.
.
```

You can select each time the row you want to change and apply the changes directly on. Just like i did.

Another point : 
After applying the division in my example the integers are transformed into float64 you can try on your example the function `series.astype('flat64')`

for `row['A'] = 1232455 / 26719856` you will get `0.046125` and not only the integer part `0` .

Maybe it will save you from having zeros every time when you do the divisions

Comment: I actually tried updating the df values like this earlier on. What it does is return index along with it. Say I have 5 selections with either True or False labels. Calculcations get done and it returns values like this `0   -0.056399,
1    1.323902`. `0` & `1` are both unwanted in this case.

Comment: I see. you can try to tansform the initial type on the columns you want to do  the calculation on. Like the column "A" by doing :

df["A"] = pd.to_numeric(df["A"])

before applying the division (and after why not)
Hope it's helpful for you.